# Alternative for dashboard without sidebar?

Tags: navigation, layout, dashboard

I'm trying to build an app with dashboard. The app would contain tables, but I don't really know a pretty nice way to display 'em. I'm using MeteorJS, and for the meantime I'm having a problem with stylesheets per module capability, so I decided for now to create dashboard without sidebar. 
Initially, I have this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHeM8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Can smebody please give me a nice alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Move the check boxes to the left
- Control the width of the columns so there is no excessive white space and everything looks compact and easy to read.